# Slice a binary number into groups of five digits

Tags: python, slice

Is there any neat trick to slice a binary number into groups of five digits in python?

'00010100011011101101110100010111' => ['00010', '00110', '10111', ... ]

Edit:
I want to write a cipher/encoder in order to generate "easy to read over the phone" tokens. The standard base32 encoding has the following disadvantages:

- Potential to generate accidental f*words
- Uses confusing chars like chars like 'I', 'L', 'O' (may be confused with 0 and 1)
- Easy to guess sequences ("AAAA", "AAAB", ...)

I was able to roll my own in 20 lines of python, thanks everybody. My encoder leaves off 'I', 'L', 'O' and 'U', and the resulting sequences are hard to guess.

Comment: Why do you have a number as a base 2 string? why not an actual integer?

Comment: I need to write encoder/cipher to generate "easy to read over the phone" tokens and my first idea was some sort of base32 encoding, each digit in base32 is 5 binary digits.

Comment: well say that, then. `base64.b32encode(yourstring)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a='00010100011011101101110100010111'
>>> [a[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(a), 5)]
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101', '11']
```

Comment: +1 Like this solution the most, as it uses basic stuff and is quite readable.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> [''.join(each) for each in zip(*[iter(s)]*5)]
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101']
```

or:

```
>>> map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)]*5))
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101']
```

[EDIT]

The question was raised by Greg Hewgill, what to do with the two trailing bits? Here are some possibilities:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>>
>>> map(''.join, izip_longest(*[iter(s)]*5, fillvalue=''))
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101', '11']
>>>
>>> map(''.join, izip_longest(*[iter(s)]*5, fillvalue=' '))
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101', '11   ']
>>>
>>> map(''.join, izip_longest(*[iter(s)]*5, fillvalue='0'))
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101', '11000']
```

Comment: I will just pad it first to the length in bits of the maximum value (which is a multiple of 5, so there will never be any trailing bits).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to group iterables, from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) examples:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your comments, you actually want base 32 strings.

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b32encode("good stuff")
'M5XW6ZBAON2HKZTG'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regular expression?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.{1,5}', '00010100011011101101110100010111')
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101', '11']
```

This will break though if your input string contains newlines, that you want in the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538981/the-most-pythonic-way-to-slice-a-python-list-every-100-elements) was duplicated by this one, so I would answer it here.

I got a more general and memory efficient answer for all this kinds of questions using [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

```
from itertools import islice
def slice_generator(an_iter, num):
    an_iter = iter(an_iter)
    while True:
        result = tuple(islice(an_iter, num))
        if not result:
           return
        yield result
```

So for this question, We can do:

```
>>> l = '00010100011011101101110100010111'
>>> [''.join(x) for x in slice_generator(l,5)]
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101', '11']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = '00010100011011101101110100010111'
>>> def splitSize(s, size):
...     return [''.join(x) for x in zip(*[list(s[t::size]) for t in range(size)])]
...  
>>> splitSize(l, 5)
['00010', '10001', '10111', '01101', '11010', '00101']
>>>
```