# The most pythonic way to slice a Python list every 100 elements

Tags: python, slice

I have a list contains many elements. I want to slice it every 100 elements to a list of several lists.

For example:

```
>>> a = range(256)
>>> b = slice(a, 100)
```

`b` should then be `[[0,1,2,...99],[100,101,102,...199],[200,201,...,255]]`.

What's the most pythonic and elegent way to do that?

Comment: @qqvc: No, not a dup of that.

Comment: This is, however, a dup of literally dozens of questions. I can't find a canonical one that gives both good answers and compares and contrasts the two, so I'll pick one arbitrarily…

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[a[i:i+100] for i in range(0, len(a), 100)]
```

[`range` takes an optional third `step` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), so `range(0, n, 100)` will be `0, 100, 200, ...`.